# How to fire and receive an event between different extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to broadcast an event to other extensions, any extension who subscribed the event would do some specified work when received the event, and make response to the extension who fired the event.

So is there any vscode APIs exposed to do that? Or any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions can communicate in a a few ways:

- Use [commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributescommands). One extension can invoke the commands of the other extension
- Use extension APIs. For this, Extension1 returns its api from the `activate` method. Then Extension2 can get ahold of it using `extensions.extensions.getExtension('extension1.id')` and call the API using the [`.exports`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/29bead35f2a5339482158a7d48f7f0f3955629e2/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L4257) object.

In both cases, extension2 should declare that it depends on extension1 using `extensionDependencies` in its `package.json`